# Use Maven's Dependency Management without the build functionality for RCP applications?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, rcp, tycho

I want to build an Eclipse RCP application, and for ease of use also want to use Maven's Dependency Management, so that dependencies are automatically resolved.

I've tried Tycho, but to no avail (I guess I haven't found the right way to set up my project yet), but I wouldn't even need Tycho's power, as I want to use Maven's dependency resolution only, and build from within Eclipse.

Is there a way to set up the Plugin project in Eclipse, so that I can use the dependency management without having to use Tycho?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: By maven dependency resolution, you mean you want maven to download all of the plugins your RCP app depends on as part of its build?

Comment: @PaulWebster, yes that's what I meant :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have searched for something simillar, but you can not use maven only for dependency management. There are several reasons, most are OSGI related, second thing is you have to have all you jar local in place to build Eclipse RCP, and not linked from another directory.

You could try couple of dirty tricks using 
http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html 
and manual copying of your dependency but that is pain, and does not work very well. The right way to do it would it be to use tycho.

Here are couple of examples that could help you to setup your plugin using tycho:

http://git.eclipse.org/c/tycho/org.eclipse.tycho.git/tree/tycho-demo

Comment: Thanks. By now I've resigned to using Tycho ;). I wouldn't wanna start copying dependencies manually... Thanks for the link to the example project, will use that as a reference point.